# Interrupt priority in STM32F103RB

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, interrupts, cortex-m3

I got a doubt about an interrupt grouping in stm32f103. In programming manual of microcontroller I found 5 ways to configure it.  [image]

But, while debugging, I found 8 ways. [image]
How is it possible to get extra 3 ways, when only 4 bits of Interrupt Priority Registers are implemented?

Comment: Maybe the tool supports all the Cotex controllers out there which might implement all bits and doesn't care for your controller restrictions?

Comment: But, the toolchain is Keil uVision5 from official website for stm32

Comment: Keil uVision supports any kind of microcontroller. Don't know if it supports limiting the register values like the Lauterbach tools do.

Comment: Ok,I understood!